# Быстрое удаление дубликатов в RichEdit

Tags: delphi

Как быстро удалить дубликаты с RichEdit1? Таким способом удаляет очень медленно:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  i := 0;
  while i < RichEdit1.Lines.Count do
  begin
    if RichEdit1.Lines.IndexOf(RichEdit1.Lines[i]) < i then
      RichEdit1.Lines.Delete(i)
    else
      inc(i);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Быстро костыль подставить - обернуть операцию в `BeginUpdate/EndUpdate`

Но, вероятно, есть решение получше, которое зависит от реальной задачи.
Например - откуда там вообще дубликаты?

Comment: Дубликаты там из за того что туда осуществляю парсинг информации из сети. И RichEdit может поместить в себя больше информации нежели Memo.

Comment: В таком случае используйте TStringList, а не визуальный компонент.

Comment: Уже сделал, интересно было с визуальным компонентом.

Comment: Быстрый способ - с сортированным списком, т.к. там не надо проходить по каждой строчке для поиска совпадений.